# How do I import wifi passwords into Fedora 19 (gnome3.8)

Tags: fedora, gnome3, networkmanager, gnome-keyring

I've upgraded from Fedora 17 to Fedora 19 and would like to transfer my wifi passwords.  In Fedora 17 they were stored in `~/.gnome2/keyrings/` whereas in Fedora 19 they are stored in `~/.local/share/keyrings/`.  Can I just copy the `login.keyring` and `user.keystore` files to the new location or is there more involved?